# Optoisolator Not Switching

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, opto-isolator, atmel

I’m working on a university project that involves switching a relay using an ILD213T optoisolator. The optoisolator is driven directly by an ATmega328p.

I had calculated the required current limiting resistor to be 220 ohms at 3.3v but it absolutely refused to switch.

I tried quickly connecting the optoisolator without a resistor and it worked great, the relay switched, however I don’t want to burn the LED out.

I gave 27 ohms a go just because I had a few of those to hand and it would switch the relay, but barely. It really struggled.

I’m at a bit of a loss as to what to do here. Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Note that the Relays are driven by 5V as per the spec.

Schematic below:

[image: Schematic]

The data sheet for the optoisolator is at: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2045803.pdf

Comment: What is the required current in the relay?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It’s 37.5mA. See: https://docs.particle.io/assets/datasheets/makerkit/spdt-relay.pdf

Comment: So current transfer ratio will be the problem. Andy's already addressed that. Do as he says and it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opto you used has a current transfer ratio (CTR) that is guaranteed to be 100% so, that's the good news but unfortunately to get 37.5 mA in the collector (to power the relay) you need 37.5 mA in the diode and its peak maximum forward current is only 30 mA.

However, it's a little more problematic than that because to push the opto-transistor into good saturation might mean the CTR reduces from 100% to 40% so you will struggle to get the opto-transistor to turn on hard enough to power the relay. See fig 11 in the opto data sheet.

I'd be tempted to add a regular BJT after the opto and then you'll only need to push maybe 5 mA into the base and this should be enough to fully activate the load. If you choose a BJT, come back and ask if it will do the job but you are looking for a BJT that has reasonable hFE at saturation (20 or more).

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I was under pressure a bit and have already rolled and soldered the board, so I’m going to have to try to push it as hard as I can. Thanks for your explanation though, that really clears things up! It’s my first time trying to use one of these.